# What happens when code in a Finally block throws an Exception?

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple block of legacy code that sits inside of a loop that crawls through some potentially bad xml node by node and which needs to be refactored as it is not working as intended:

```
Try
   xmlFrag.LoadXml("<temproot>" & strXMLfragment & "</temproot>")
   writer.WriteRaw(strXMLfragment)
Catch ex As Exception
   InvalidXML = True
End Try
```

What this block is *meant* to do is check for valid xml and then write the xml out. What it *actually* does is check for invalid xml and then write the xml out **only** if it is valid. So it needs to be fixed to work as intended.

My first attempt at a fix:

```
Try
   xmlFrag.LoadXml("<temproot>" & strXMLfragment & "</temproot>")
   'writer.WriteRaw(strXMLfragment)
Catch ex As Exception
   InvalidXML = True
Finally
   writer.WriteRaw(strXMLfragment)
End Try
```

This works on my test data but I am concerned that WriteRaw may throw an exception on other data. I haven't found a conclusive statement about what will cause [WriteRaw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0755ytay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to throw an exception and what will happen when code in a [Finally block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) throws an exception.

So I tried rewriting it like this:

```
Try
   xmlFrag.LoadXml("<temproot>" & strXMLfragment & "</temproot>")
Catch ex As Exception
   InvalidXML = True
End Try
Try
   writer.WriteRaw(strXMLfragment)
Catch
End Try
```

Frankly it looks ugly as hell. Is there a more elegant way to refactor this or will the first attempt be suitable?

Comment: Generally, you should not put code, that potentially can throw an exception, inside a Finally block. Good use for it would be closing DB connections, doing rollback on transactions etc. Writing to a file in a `Finally` block can throw an exception, same as reporting something to an external service etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I came up with this profoundly simple and elegant refactoring:

```
Try
   writer.WriteRaw(strXMLfragment)
   xmlFrag.LoadXml("<temproot>" & strXMLfragment & "</temproot>")

Catch ex As Exception
   InvalidXML = True
End Try
```

With the WriteRaw line executing first it will always write out the XML unless it throws an exception. Then the LoadXml line can test for validity without interfering with writing the xml out. This way the InvalidXML flag is set as designed and there won't be any unexpected exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

When an excpetion is raised in a `Finally` block, nothing special happens: the exception is  propagated out and up like any other exception, and code *after* the exception in this finally block will not be executed.

Your first attempt will fail if `strXMLfragment` is `null` or an empty string (or due to a [already running asynchronous operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0755ytay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

So if you really want to handle/swallow all exceptions, you'll have to use two `Try` blocks.

Comment: ... or create a `Try` block within the `Finally` block.

Answer (score 3):

To make it cleaner, you might want to pull your first Try/Catch into it's own private function and make it reusable:

```
Private Function TryParseXml(ByVal xml as String) as Boolean
    Try
        XDocument.Parse(xml)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Then wrap your writer.WriteRaw call in it's own Try/Catch.

```
Dim myXml = "<temproot>" & strXMLfragment & "</temproot>"
If TryParseXml(myXml) Then
    xmlFrag.LoadXml(myXml)
Else
    Try
        writer.WriteRaw(strXMLfragment)
    Catch ex as Exception
        ' handle exception
    End Try
End If
```

Yes, ultimately this is using two Try/Catch blocks.  There is no real way around this as the only real way to determine if Xml is valid is to attempt to parse it and wait for it to blow up.